# How to categorize tweets using Twitter API

Tags: sttwitterapi

I'm planning to create a news website using twitter API to fetch tweets of specific news resource accounts. Is there anyway to categorize them into sports, break news, culture ... etc?

Here's the example of sample timeline result

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

Answer (score 1):

Aside from doing your own post processing with location, text or bio NLP, this isn't something included from Twitter in the raw Tweet payload today.  However this could be a good [feature request](https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com/forums/921790-twitter-developer-labs?category_id=362647) for endpoints built through the new [Labs program](https://developer.twitter.com/en/labs) that Twitter is running.